# onTouchListener analog for Rad Studio XE5

Tags: android, delphi-xe5

Need onTouchListener analog for Rad Studio XE5,because it havent such function:(.
Is there any other way to work with multiple touches(NOT GESTURES,i need work with 2+touches at screen(events for them,coordinates,etc))?

Comment: I'n not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  Simple touches are treated like mouse clicks, and the events are mouse or click events.  How is what you are trying to do different from that?

Comment: I mean,i need this:i click on TWO elements(click 1st,and after,without removing finger,click 2nd),and need to get event on BOTH of them